# Can I use CComPtr inside of a std::map?

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, smart-pointers

I'm writing a program in Windows COM in C++ and I'm using `CComPtr` for smart pointers.

The question I can't find answer to is - Can I use `CComPtr` inside of a `std::map`.

I have the following code fragment (simplified):

```
std::map<int, CComPtr<IErrorInfo> > ErrorMap;
```

I wish to maintain this mapping between `int`s and `IErrorInfo` error infos.

However I'm not sure if I can do the following:

```
CComPtr<IErrorInfo> result;
GetErrorInfo(0, &pErrInfo);

ErrorMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, result));
```

I'm concerned about ownership of the `result` smart pointer and if it will get released correctly when `ErrorMap` gets destroyed?

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your CComPtr in [CAdapt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs6acf5x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this to work.

> The adapter class CAdapt is useful because many container classes
>   (such as the STL container classes) expect to be able to obtain the
>   addresses of their contained objects using the address-of operator.
>   The redefinition of the address-of operator can confound this
>   requirement, typically causing compilation errors and preventing the
>   use of the unadapted type with that container. CAdapt provides a way
>   around those problems.

Comment: In C++11 you shouldn't have to do this, as the CopyConstructible requirement no longer requires `operator &` to work in the normal way.